# Powershell show running processes

Tags: powershell

How to get the "running processes" of Component Services via Powershell?

See this picture:

[image: Example of Component Services with Trip1 running]

In this picture you see a Trip1 running with a PID id behind (39808 in this case).
I would like to retrieve this number via Powershell, but do not know how to do so.

The code found for getting the COM+ Application is:

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$apps = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")
$apps.Populate()
```

The variable "$apps" gives me then the installed components.

But how to know if the component defined is running yes or no? And how to get that PID?

Comment: Have you looked up what members a ComAdminCatalog object has? `$apps` will probably be an array of such objects, so that you should be able to inspect a particular member by referencing `$apps[$n].«membername»`.

Comment: While you won't get quite as much information as from proper research, you might find piping the array to `Get-Member` to be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Applications` collection contains all applications registered on the machine, not just the ones with running instances.

To discover those, query for the [`ApplicationInstances` collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cossdk/applicationinstances) instead:

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$apps = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")
$apps.Populate()

$appInstances = $comAdmin.GetCollection("ApplicationInstances")
$appInstances.Populate()

foreach ($appInstance in $appInstances) {
  # identify the associated application
  $appKey = $appInstance.Value('Application')
  $appName = ($apps |Where-Object Key -eq $appKey).Name

  # output along with hosting process id
  [pscustomobject]@{
    ApplicationName = $appName
    ProcessId = $appInstance.Value('ProcessID')
  }
}
```